# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 11597: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, macos, encoding, jupyter-notebook, text-classification

I am using well known 20 Newsgroups data set for text categorisation in jupyter. When I try to open and read file on my Mac, it fails at decoding step. I tried to read the file in byte format, which works but I further need to work with it as string. I tried to encode it but it fails with the error.

**Code**

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  file_read=f.read()
  file_read.decode("us-ascii")
```

**Error**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 11597: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Us-ascii is file encoding I found when typing in terminal: `file -I file_name`. I tried other encodings but none works. 
I further want to remove punctuation and count words in the file. Is there a way how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you try using str(file_read, 'US-ASCII')?

Comment: Try with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='ascii', errors=None) and check the validity of the data.

Comment: same error message

Comment: Try with errors='ignore'

Comment: OMG that worked! I thought it will be more complicated like setting exceptions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky without looking at the file. However this works most of the time

```
from codecs import open
file_path = "file_name"
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
  file_read=f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting error to ignore resolved the problem, thanks N M. The code looks like:

```
ref_file=open(ref_file_path, 'r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') 
file_read=ref_file.read()
```

The code further treats it as a one big string. Note that although the error was about decoding 0xff it was not UTF-16 coding.